# Install php extension if PHP is already installed

Tags: php, calendar

Is it possible to install a php extension if PHP is already installed without having to rebuild PHP? I need to install the calendar extension but I don't like to build PHP, I just installed it with `apt-get` and did not builded it from source.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php

Comment: The output is empty

Comment: And what is wrong with `apt-get install php-calendar` if using Jessie(oldstable) or just installing `php7.0-common` or `php7.3-common` on newer versions? It seems that this module was integrated to php common package on Debian - https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=php-calendar - What version of Debian are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed PHP with `apt-get`, then you also need to install any required PHP modules in the same way.

In your case you need to do this:

```
apt-get install php-calendar
```